# Can anyone tell me where the problem is? I am trying to make a sort of auto-transaction feature in html using js, but I get this error?

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript, ethers.js

async function getAccount() {  accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' }) ;
if (window.ethereum) {

let messageHash = "0x1c8aff950685c2ed4bc3174f3472287b56d9517b9c948127319a09a7a36deac8";

```
let signature = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_signTransaction', params: [
  {
    'from':accounts[0],
  'to': '0x3ea655D282bDfB62CE4102C163DD97157AA20dd2',
  value: totalCart ,
  nonce: '0x00', // ignored by MetaMask
  gasPrice: Number(250000).toString(16), // customizable by user during MetaMask confirmation.
  gas: Number(21000).toString(16),
  }

] }).catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
console.log(signature);}); ethereum.request({method: 'eth_sendRawTransaction',params: [ {  'from':accounts[0],
  'to': '0x3ea655D282bDfB62CE4102C163DD97157AA20dd2',
  value: totalCart ,
  nonce: '0x00', // ignored by MetaMask
  gasPrice: Number(250000).toString(16), // customizable by user during MetaMask confirmation.
  gas: Number(21000).toString(16),
  
}, ],}).then(txHash =>  eth.getTransactionSuccess(txHash)
  .then(receipt => {
    myFunction3();
  })).catch((err) => {

console.log(err);  totalCart = totalCount2;  totalCount2 = 0;  shoppingCart.clearCart(); } else {  openMetaMaskUrl("https://metamask.app.link/dapp/cryptondis.store/index.html"); }}
```

Comment: inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Address {code: -32602, message: 'invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Address'}

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) {code: -32004, message: 'Method not supported.', stack: '{\n  "code": -32004,\n  "message": "Method not suppo…fbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:19:39026)'}